# Hyundai Tucson has trouble shifting when ESC and DBC lights come on

Tags: hyundai, shifting, warning-light, bcm

I own a 2011 Hyundai Tucson Limited.

Sometimes, seemingly randomly, the Electronic Stability Control light will turn yellow, [image]

and the Downhill Brake Control light will turn red.  [image]

This sometimes causes problems my shifting. When I am in park, I can't shift out of park (I think sometimes depressing the brake pedal harder than normal will solve this). When I am in drive, I can't shift past neutral. I have to resort to the Shift Lock Release button in order to continue shifting.

I have checked the OBD II codes while this is happening and nothing shows up.

Does anyone have a recommendation for what the problem is and if I can fix this at home?

Comment: Have you checked to see if you have any error codes via your ODBII port?

Comment: A family member had the exact same issue. Hyundai has a repair bulleting for this problem. Contact your local hyundai dealer and have them fix it. This is a safety issue. I dont remember what they did to fix it though. :)

Comment: This service bulletin may be the applicable one that racefever mentioned.    https://www.automd.com/tsb/bulletin_b348207/

Comment: When this happens do the brake lights work? Not being able to go out of park and not being able to go from drive to park is a shift interlock issue. It could be as simple as the brake switch failing.